# Deactivate macport

Tags: macports

I am trying to install the macport demeter using the following line in mac terminal:

```
sudo port install demeter
```

I get the error message

```
Error: Failed to activate demeter: Image error: /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Ifeffit.pm is being used by the active p5.34-ifeffit port.  Please deactivate this port first, or use 'port -f activate demeter' to force the activation.
```

I have two questions:
(1) Why am I getting this error message? Have I accidentally got two copies of demeter?
(2) How can I deactivate this port? (I'd rather deactivate it then use the force activate option)

When I run

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP
```

I can't actually see 'p5.34-ifeffit port' in the list of ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the demeter port. It should not install the files of the ifeffit perl module, but instead declare a dependency on p5.34-ifeffit.

Please file a ticket at https://trac.macports.org/newticket.

You can force the activation, but that will overwrite the file(s) in question with the copies from the demeter port. Uninstalling that port later will delete those files, which may then in turn break other software that relies on p5.34-ifeffit.

Comment: Thanks, I will file a ticket

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with Demeter but you might try asking for help on the MacPorts users mailing list:

https://lists.macports.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users

Or raise a ticket on the MacPorts Trac system:

https://trac.macports.org/newticket?port=demeter

Craig